# Analyze a bunch of files and categorize them according to their content, content-duplicates possible with different format

Tags: search, storage

I have material such as images, PDFs, DOC and DOCX with a lot of duplicated items but in different format. I may have a paper in PDF and then I have it also in DOC and DOCX. I want to somehow categorize all material according to the content of material. If PDF and DOC have the same content, they should be categorized to the same folder. My first idea was ssdeep and Adope PDF's search for PDF -files but slow solutions.

> - Does there exist some method that would categorize a massive directory with duplicates according to their contents?
> - Please, note that the duplicateness is a statistical measure in a way: if enough similarity, then categorize to the same folder. How can
>     I do this kind of categorization in Mac?
> - Some ready software for this?

*Please, add labels such as `categorization` to better match this thread. Some better labels?*

Comment: Are you looking for a) software to automatically analyze a bunch of files and categorize them, b) software to store these documents in, c) a proposal on how to setup a folder structure etc. to store them or d) something totally different?

Comment: @patrix I mean A.